# Turing machine for language $\{a^p | p~\text{is a prime number}\}$

Tags: turing-machines

I am trying to find a Turing Machine for the above language. I am trying to do it with one tape, to start with. However, I am not quite sure about how to keep track of the number of a's in the string. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do it with as many tapes as you need (as long as it's a constant number) and use the known transformations form multi-tape to single-tape Turing machines.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a constant number of tapes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *very* slow turing program that works on binary numbers at http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html (just go to the example programs); it could easily be adapted to unary.

Answer (score 0):

We'll try to construct the TM below. Given input $a^p$, our TM will accept if and only if $p$ is prime. This TM will contain an input tape and a tape for its factors, and it starts with $a^p$ on its input tape.

1. If the input is $\varepsilon$ or $a$, the TM rejects right away. (Why? Because $0$ and $1$ are not primes.)
2. If (1) above does not hold, then initialise the factors tape with the string $aa$.
3. If the input length is the same as the length of the string on the divisor tape, then the Turing machine halts and accepts. (How would we implement this? The TM seeks to the starts of the strings on both the input and factors tapes, and both heads move together at once. If one head sees some character $\mathfrak{c}$ before another, then the strings have different lengths; otherwise, they have the same length.)
4. The TM then determines whether the length of the value on the input tape is divisible by the length of the value on the factors tape - it halts and rejects if this is the case. (How might we implement this? The TM would move all the way to the starts of both the input and the factors tapes and moves the heads together at once. If the factors head sees $\mathfrak{c}$ while the input head sees $a$, then the TM will reset the factors head to the beginning of its string and continues reading. If the input head sees $\mathfrak{c}$ while the factors head sees $a$, then the factor isn't really a factor (it doesn't uniformly divide the input). If both heads see $\mathfrak{c}$ at once, then the factor actually does divide the input.)
5. If the current factor doesn't divide the input, then the TM increments the value on the factors tape and reverts to step (3) above, repeating the loop. (How would you implement this? Just go all the way to the end of the factor and append an $a$.)

Depending on which TM model you're following, the TM will vary a bit, but should still be a variation of the above. I used two tapes, but there are a number of routines you can use to compress it all to one tape (for example by adding a marker $\mathfrak{m}$ after a number of steps on the tape etc). Regardless, the point is that as the TM rejects the numbers $0$, $1$, and every $p \in [2, p-1]$ such that $p$ has a factor (i.e. all unary strings $a$ of composite length), it only accepts those $p \geq 2$ that do not pass trial division for all numbers $< p$; namely the prime $p$.